# running NextJS in tandem with ASP Classic IIS Server, for certain routes

Tags: iis, next.js, iisnode

I am being asked to look into some things, related to a 20 year old ASP Classic site, hosted on IIS.  They've injected React node apps for a few things, but it's integrated, not separate.

A complete app overhaul IS needed, but it's not going to happen anytime soon...So I'd like to suggest moving certain parts, slowly, to a new web app.  Probably built with NextJS due to the server side capabilities, and hosted in Vercel.

How can I setup the ASP/IIS Server, so that certain routes go to a completely different server?
If the user is logged in, will that cause issues crossing different servers?  I would assume just pass along an auth token...

Any other ideas?

Comment: 1. Next.js developers don't offer documentation on IIS, so you'd better host your planned web app on Linux. 2. Set up a reverse proxy in front so that it can distribute traffic based on URLs to either classic ASP or your Next.js app. That should be fairly simple and straight forward.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Ouch .. what a shame, IIS is soooo useful.